# Get a substring using 2 patterns in Dart?

Tags: dart

How can I pull out a string from two different patterns either side of the string I want: eg

```
 String s=  bg_img_pulloutthisstring@s_200
```

How can I pull out `pulloutthisstring` from s?

Comment: You should be *very clear* about what you want. What are the delimiters? Is it "bg_img_" and "@s_200" or just "_" and "@"? Can the delimiters occur inside the match? That is: Are you going for a maximal or minimal match in cases where there might be more than one? A `RegExp` can likely solve the problem in any case (and so can non-RegExp code), but it can only do one thing at a tie, so you should be careful to solve the *correct* problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to use a Regular Expression and use a match group:

```
void main() {
  const s = 'bg_img_pulloutthisstring@s_200';
  print(RegExp(r'bg_img_(.*)@s_200').firstMatch(s).group(1)); // pulloutthisstring
}
```